# Сигналы Django, удаление файла

Tags: python, django

Привет, такая ситуация не могу написать сигнал для Django, например при обновлении или при удалении картинки в поле imagefield, чтобы он с файловой системы тоже удалился, можете пожалуйста помочь

Comment: Добавьте код, что Вы делаете для реализации? Вопрос не полный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я в своих продакшенах использую такой код

При обновлении объекта:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.ImageField(...)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is not None:
            old_self = MyModel.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            if old_self.my_field and self.my_field != old_self.my_field:
                old_self.my_field.delete(False)
        return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

При удалении объекта:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=MyModel)
def myfield_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.my_field.name:
        instance.my_field.delete(False)
```

Comment: Правда, после соседнего ответа я засомневался, лучше `pre_delete` или `post_delete`

Comment: Извини, но это же для изменения одного же поля ? а не для целого query set?

Comment: @АдлетСарсембаев а про query set в вопросе ничего и нет) Если вам это не подходит, давайте подробности в вопрос тогда

Comment: Просто, я читал много в интернете и там все говорят о queryset, и я не знаю как сделать так чтобы при изменении поле связанное с картинкой или при удалении картинки все изменения происходили еще на файловой системе и извини за неправильно сформированный вопрос !

Comment: @АдлетСарсембаев вообще хз при чём тут queryset

Comment: @АдлетСарсембаев сигнал срабатывает при удалении каждого экземпляра модели. Если вы где-гибудь вызовите метод `delete()` для QuerySet'а, сигнал сработает столько раз, сколько в QuerySet'е было элементов.